# Irreducible polynomial iff the condition is satisfied

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I am asked to show that the polynomial $f(x)=x^n+1 \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ is irreducible if and only if $n=2^k$ for any integer $k\geq 0$.

Could you give me some hints what I could do to show this??

Comment: If $n\ne 2^k$, then $n$ has an odd divisor. Do you know a factorization of $x^r+1$ where $r$ is odd?

Comment: Could explain me why when n is not a power of 2, then it has an odd divisor??

Comment: Look at its prime factorization. Unless $n=1$, if $n$ is not a power of $2$, then it must be divisible by some other prime, and all the other primes are odd.

Answer (score 1):

$\Rightarrow$ Assume by contradiction that $n \neq 2^k$. Then it has an odd divisor. Use the formula for $a^k+b^k$...

$\Leftarrow$ Use the fact that $(X^n+1)(X^n-1)=X^{2n}-1$. Write this as product of cyclotomic polynomials and use induction by $k$.

Comment: Capital $X$ small $x$ confusion :P

Comment: @Chandrasekhar ty, I make this capital mistake often :)

Comment: @N.S.Could explain me why when n is not a power of 2, then it has an odd divisor??

Comment: @MaryStar Take the prime factorization of $n$. If $2$ is the only prime, it means that $n$ is a power of two. Otherwise, there is another prime, but this prime is an odd divisor of $n$.